# How to fix 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' when adding hibernate-validator dependency in maven?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I would like to find how to fix

> 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException'

when adding hibernate-validator in maven dependencies ?
Thanks for your help !

Maven dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hibernate validator application in the model :

```
@NotNull(message="Name must not be null")
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
```

Expected result is shown on this tutorial : 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank

Error message :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'applicationController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: entities.service.IApplicationService
>   entities.controller.ApplicationController.applicationService; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'applicationService': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: entities.dao.IApplicationDao
>   entities.service.ApplicationServiceImpl.applicationDao; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'applicationDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   entities.dao.ApplicationDaoImpl.sf; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error
>   activating Bean Validation integration

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?